# Testing rspec and capybara with dynamic dom

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I am try to write feature test with `rpsec`, `capybara`, I have a form with input like image, when I add text on input then click `Add` button, I will use javascript to append dynamic dom `test label`. I try to write feature test but when I run this test

```
    fill_in 'message_setting_message_settings_labels_text', with: 'test label'
    find('span', text: 'Add').click
    expect(page).to have_content('test label')
```

The page can not find text `test label`. It seem capybara not execute javascript action right ?. Anyone test like this can help me ?
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#using-capybara-with-rspec

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the link that @max has shared, you need to include `js: true` in the `feature` line or `describe` line of your rspec.

But there is always a potential race condition between the javascript and the Ruby. I can think of three race scenarios...

1. If there is an ajax request that needs to complete before the label appears on the page. You need to wait for the ajax to complete. With all credit to Thoughtbot for this, you can use the helper that they describe here: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara
2. If you have any animations that could delay the appearance of the element on the page (e.g. slideDown etc.) These can, and should, be disabled in the test environment. I use this:

```rb
<body class=<%= "no-animation" if Rails.env.test? %> >

<style>
.no-animation * {
  /*CSS transitions*/
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  transition: none !important;

  /*CSS transition properties*/
  -webkit-transition-property: none !important;
  -moz-transition-property: none !important;
  -o-transition-property: none !important;
  -ms-transition-property: none !important;
  transition-property: none !important;

  /*CSS transforms*/
  -webkit-transform: none !important;
  -moz-transform: none !important;
  -o-transform: none !important;
  -ms-transform: none !important;
  transform: none !important;

  /*CSS animations*/
  -webkit-animation: none !important;
  -moz-animation: none !important;
  -o-animation: none !important;
  -ms-animation: none !important;
  animation: none !important;
}
```

3. Even without ajax or animations, there can be a race, in which case the brute force approach of waiting with `sleep(0.5)` is the only (albeit ugly) solution.